# Is there a time limit for the remove media screen after installing Ubuntu with ISO?

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

When you are done installing ISO using USB, remove usb from the screen and press Enter I can see the screen, but if I keep it on this screen, will the ISO be reinstalled?

If reinstalled, how many hours does it take to reinstall?

Comment: No it will not be re-installed.  It'll just sit there waiting for you to remove media & press Enter and reboot.  On some hardware the reboot doesn't happen though  (*hardware/firmware specific*).  You can use *live* media for mere minutes, hours or even days! - there is no time limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it will not be re-installed.  It'll just sit there waiting for you to remove media & press Enter and reboot.

On some hardware the reboot doesn't happen though  (*hardware/firmware specific*).

You can use *live* media for mere minutes, hours or even days! - there is no time limit.

*Do note:  Ubuntu provides many ISOs for many different architectures, with many installers available; so what occurs on one ISO for a given release/architecture may differ to another release/architecture, but most are similar.  This answer is mostly based on Desktop (inc. *flavor*) ISOs for *i386* or *amd64* architectures.*

I've had QA-test installs take less than 2 minutes; others have taken hours. The hardware involved plays a huge part, as does the install itself (*minimal installs usually take longer as everything is installed, then files get removed to make the minimal install - but it'll vary on product/release/ISO*)

Comment: Installs taking *hours* is **not** normal... but you can perform *Upgrades via re-install* and use install types where *manually installed* packages on your system get auto-reinstalled, which means they'll get downloaded from the internet when not available on the ISO... With slow internet & a bloated load of packages to be re-installed - it takes time!  but it works  :)